# ES6 : How to export this variable of node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

There is a piece of code that querying data from mongodb with `node.js`:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , assert = require('assert');


//a query that returns all the documents
var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  var collection = db.collection('documents');
  // Find some documents
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs)
    callback(docs);
  });
}


var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  var result = findDocuments(db, function() {
      db.close();
  });
});


//export the query result,but it doesn't work because it is a local variable in `MongoClient.connect()`
export {result}
```

**Question:**
I want to export the variable `result`, but it doesn't work because it is a local variable in `MongoClient.connect()`.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Define it outside the function like

```
var result
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it globally in the document.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , assert = require('assert');


var result; //define it out here to be able to use it on anywhere

//a query that returns all the documents
var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  var collection = db.collection('documents');
  // Find some documents
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs)
    callback(docs);
  });
}


var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  result = findDocuments(db, function() {   //give it its value
      db.close();
  });
});


//export the query result,but it doesn't work because it is a local variable in `MongoClient.connect()`
export {result}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ES6`, I would recommend to use the keywords `let/const` instead of `var`.

---

Now about your issue why would you export result that way?

You should create a function `connect()` and export it. Then in your controller, call this function and handle whatever the outcome is.

Your connect here is totally asynchronous and uncontrolled, which is very bad behavior.

---

Exemple of what to do :

**file mongodb.es6**

```
export default class Mongodb {

  connect() {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

**file main.es6**

```
 const mongodbObject = new Mongodb();

 mongodbObject.connect()
   .then(() => {
     // I am connected so I can do whatever I want
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     // I have an error and do something about it
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like this!

This will **ONLY** query the data when the file is being executed. I don't see any reason to do it this way.

Instead expose a function from this file, which will connect to the DB, query it and return the result object, **everytime you call it**.

```
export {
   getResult: function(query, callback) {
     // Connection URL
     var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
     // Use connect method to connect to the server
     MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

        if (err) return callback(err);
        console.log("Connected correctly to server");

        result = findDocuments(db, function() {
           db.close();
        });
        callback(null, result);
     });
   }
}
```